# The "perfect" egrep in a file with a lot of garbage and one huge line only

Tags: grep

I have a file with a lot of garbage(strange chars,comments,etc),the file contain some links which I want to extract with grep.
File is really big,over 2000 words in one line.
If I try this line works perfect with the exact match

```
egrep -Eo --text "abcde192848.bmp" Untitled\ 1.txt
```

Return correctly abcde192848.bmp.
But there are a lot of bmp links and I cannot get it,if I try

```
egrep -Eo --text "^abc*+.bmp" Untitled\ 1.txt
```

Return nothing.
My question is: how to grep from one line all strings which start with abc and end with bmp?
The file is similar to this

```
***strangechars***urlabc1239.bmp****sstrangechars***urlabc394848.bmp***
```

The line is very big and contain a lot of .bmp "urls".
The output I want must return

```
abc449048.bmp
abc231848.bmp
abc144848.bmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
grep -o 'abc[a-z0-9]*\.bmp'
```

- `[a-z0-9]*` this will match zero or more of lowercase alphabets and digits
- `\.` this will match a `.` character literally

Why `^abc*+.bmp` doesn't work

- `^` is start of line anchor, so at best you can get one match per line, not all matches in the line
- `c*` will match `c` zero or more times, perhaps you intended `*` to work like in shell glob?
- `+` not sure what this would do in combination of `*+`
- `.` will match any character, not just `.` character